# Copy and Paste Cell Value from One Sheet to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with VBA as I'm a bit rusty now with the language.

Question: How do I copy cell value from column H in the "Source" sheet (see "Source" image) to its corresponding column cell in the "Destination" sheet (depicted in the "Destination" image).

I tried For Looping each row in the "Source" Sheet and see if the row values in column D, E, F and G match all the column values in the "Destination" sheet and then copy the value if all variables match but always come across errors.

Can anyone help?

[image: Source]

[image: Destination]

Comment: Have a look at PivotTables. No need to write any code at all.

Comment: :) That's one way to look at it. But I'm planning on creating a power automate / UiPath program to run this automatically

Comment: Then please show your attempt and explain what exactly your issue was in your code: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)